# How can I show two values in one RecycleView?

Tags: android

I have the BaseBall Team and the BasketBall Team Table. I want to bring data from each of these two tables and show it to one RecycleView.

So I was going to designate ViewType, but there was an error.

The table contains data from players with the same name, so the results are unconditionally taken from each table.

I tried to put the results of the two tables in one list, then put the list in the Adapter to show it in RecycleView.

I had an error trying to put the results of two tables in one list.

What should I do?

It's MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    SearchView searchView;
    ApiInterface apiInterface;
    Adapter adapter;
    List list = new ArrayList();
    List<BaseBallInfo> baseBallInfoList;
    List<BasketBallInfo> basketBallInfoList;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                search(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void search(final String name) {
        apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<List<BaseBallInfo>> call = apiInterface.getBaseBallInfo(name);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<BaseBallInfo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<BaseBallInfo>> call, Response<List<BaseBallInfo>> response) {
                baseBallInfoList = response.body();
                list.add(baseBallInfoList);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<BaseBallInfo>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("ErrorMessage", t.toString());
            }
        });

        Call<List<BasketBallInfo>> call2 = apiInterface.getBasketBallInfo(name);
        call2.enqueue(new Callback<List<BasketBallInfo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<BasketBallInfo>> call, Response<List<BasketBallInfo>> response) {
                basketBallInfoList = response.body();
                list.add(basketBallInfoList);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<BasketBallInfo>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("ErrorMessage", t.toString());
            }
        });

        adapter = new Adapter(MainActivity.this, list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

It's Adapter.

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List list;

    public Adapter(Context context, List list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(list.get(position) instanceof BaseBallInfo) {
            return 0;
        }

        return 1;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == 0) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_baseball, parent, false);
            BaseBallViewHolder holder = new BaseBallViewHolder(view);
            return holder;
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_basketball, parent, false);
            BasketBallViewHolder holder = new BasketBallViewHolder(view);
            return holder;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        if(this.getItemViewType(position) == 0) {
            BaseBallInfo baseBallInfo = (BaseBallInfo)list.get(position);
            BaseBallViewHolder holder = (BaseBallViewHolder) viewHolder;
            holder.nameTextView.setText(baseBallInfo.getName());
            holder.battingTextView.setText(baseBallInfo.getBatting_avg());
        } else if(this.getItemViewType(position) == 1) {
            BasketBallInfo basketBallInfo = (BasketBallInfo)list.get(position);
            BasketBallViewHolder holder = (BasketBallViewHolder) viewHolder;
            holder.name2TextView.setText(basketBallInfo.getName());
            holder.positionTextView.setText(basketBallInfo.getPos());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "No Result", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public static class BaseBallViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView nameTextView, battingTextView;

        public BaseBallViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
            battingTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.battingTextView);
        }
    }

    public static class BasketBallViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView name2TextView, positionTextView;

        public BasketBallViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name2TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name2TextView);
            positionTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.positionTextView);
        }
    }
}
```

It's Error Log.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.recyclerviewprac01, PID: 10185
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.example.recyclerviewprac01.BasketBallInfo
        at com.example.recyclerviewprac01.Adapter.onBindViewHolder(Adapter.java:57)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3540)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7139)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7139)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:403)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7139)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7139)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7139)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:992)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3301)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2028)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2330)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1888)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8511)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Plz Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't tryed and solved this but I think the problem is:

in the activity you are adding a lists of 'BaseBallInfo' and 'BasketBallInfo' that you are getting using a network operation (you have Response<List> as response, so it is a LIST not a SINGLE OBJECT ).

Next you pass this list (that is a List of Lists) to the Adapter.
Then you are trying to get an item from this list and converting it to 'BaseBallInfo' or 'BasketBallInfo', but if you do list.get(position) you have a List of 'BaseBallInfo' or 'BasketBallInfo' items, not a single item.

I didn't understand exactly what you want as final result, but if all the code is right, so you should convert 'list' in the activity o a list of objects ('BaseBallInfo' or 'BasketBallInfo') instead of a list of list of object.

Try do 'list.addAll(...);' instead of 'list.add()', in the network response callback. You need 'list' to be a list of objects not a list of lists of objects.

Hope this is helpful and solves,
have a nice coding and day